# Using a list to access a function in dart flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I access a function through a list?

I have something like this:

```
  List processList = [
    [001, 'Volume', 0.8,0,0],
    [002, 'Complexity', 0.5,0,0],
    [003, 'Silence', 0.3,0,0],
    [004, 'Notice', 0.3,0,0],
    ....];
```

And I want 001, 002 etc to be functions that I can call through

```
processList[i][0] ();
```

Like a list of functions...

I cannot figure out the syntax for this somehow, the only thing I can achieve is filling the List with the result of the function, but that is not what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
void main() {
  List processList = [
    [(){print('London');}, 'Volume', 0.8, 0, 0],
    [(){print('Aarhus');}, 'Complexity', 0.5, 0, 0],
    [(){print('Munich');}, 'Silence', 0.3, 0, 0],
    [(){print('LA');}, 'Notice', 0.3, 0, 0],
  ];
  int i = 3;
  processList[i][0]();
}
```

prints `LA`. Looks at [typedefs](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) for ways to declare function signatures.